# Is this tab notation a "soft pulloff"?

Tags: tablature

I've seen several tab notations like the following:

[image]

What does it mean? You hold the original note for a bar, then do a "soft pulloff" (take your finger off the fretboard) for the next bar?

Answer (score 1):

That's how I understand it, yes. I often find this sort of notation in tapping parts.

Make sure that you time the first note's vibrato to the moment where you transition to the second note with a pulloff. ;)